# Groovy Syntax Checking in Java

Tags: java, groovy

I'm implementing a Web-based Groovy code editor and need to check the code for syntax errors. The Java implementation below works OK but the resulting message contains some undesired elements (in bold). I'm looking for a way to list warnings and errors individually. 
I'm using this maven dependency: [groovy-all 2.1.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.1.1)

```
try {
    new GroovyShell().parse(groovyCode);            
} catch(CompilationFailedException cfe) {
    System.out.println(cfe.getMessage());
}
```

Output:

```
startup failed:

Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: n @ line 1, column 19.

def factorial(n)  n == 1 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1) }
                         ^

1 error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would not make much sense to parse the error message. Try to look into

```
CompilationFailedException.getUnit()
ProcessingUnit.getErrorCollector()
ErrorCollector.getWarnings() & getErrors()
```

**EDIT**

Ok, looks like `unit` is null on the `CompilationFailedException`. Try catching `MultipleCompilationErrorsException` instead:

```
try {
    new GroovyShell().parse(groovyCode);
} catch(MultipleCompilationErrorsException cfe) {
    ErrorCollector errorCollector = cfe.getErrorCollector();
    System.out.println("Errors: "+errorCollector.getErrorCount());
}
```

Btw, take a look at the `ErrorCollector` sources, you might find `write` method useful to output the info about compilation errors.

Comment: I had tried the cfe.getUnit() path, but it always returned null.